# New Hash from 2 Arrays: Arr1 = Key, Arr2 = Value where Arr2 is Random

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Newbie here. Scratching my head.

I have 2 Arrays:

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

I want to make a Hash using `arr1` elements as the key and `arr2` elements as the value. I want `arr2` (or `arr1`, doesn't really matter) to be random.

Result example:

```
hash = {"a"=>"3", "b"=>"1", "c"=>"2", "d"=>"4"}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow also has documentation and many examples, you can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/288/hashes/8854/conversion-to-and-from-arrays#t=201610192303377711573

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two Arrays into Hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174913/combine-two-arrays-into-hash)

Answer (score 3):

So there are a fair number of ways to do this, but I'll do it in my favorite way

```
arr1.zip(arr2.shuffle).to_h
```

This shuffles (randomizes) `arr2` so `arr2` becomes `['3', '1', '2', '4']` (for example) and then zips `arr1` and `arr2` together into a multidimensional array `[['a', '3'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '2'], ['d', '4']]`. Then `to_h` turns this into a hash with the first element as the key and the second as the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure similar questions were answered in S.O. before, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174913/combine-two-arrays-into-hash).

Anyway, you can just do:

```
> hash = Hash[arr1.zip(arr2.shuffle)]
=> {"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"4"}
```

Tip: don't forget to take an extensive look at basic structures' documentation.